# Why doesn't the AOSP-provided emulator based on QEMU 2.12 receive version upgrades for QEMU anymore?

Tags: android, android-source, qemu

My supervisor has recently shown a keen interest in this type of engineering question and has suggested merging the downstream changes for the AOSP-provided emulator's QEMU into version 6.1. However, the official support for the emulator remains at QEMU 2.12.
I'm curious why the official team hasn't pursued the downstream merge.
By the way, I have read the guidelines in the official Android code repository for merging downstream QEMU changes, but I have encountered various cryptic error messages when running the official scripts. Has anyone else had a similar experience? Or has anyone been able to successfully run this script(build-qemu-android.sh) without encountering any issues?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W6NA.png)

The answers or discussions about why the official team hasn't pursued the downstream merge.
Any idea about the script build-qemu-android.sh is also welcomed.